# Remove Object from NSMutableDictionary after some Time

Tags: ios, cocoa, selector, nstimer, nsmutabledictionary

i want to remove some objects from a NSMutableDictionary after some Time.

I have:

```
//first Method start
    PedObjectTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(fireTimer:) userInfo:PedMessage repeats:YES];
    [PedMessage setObject:PedObjectTimer forKey:@"Timer"];
    [PedObjects setObject:[PedMessage copy] forKey:[PedMessage objectForKey:@"ObjectID"]];
//first Method end



- (void) fireTimer:(NSTimer*)theTimer {

    NSLog(@"%@",PedObjects);
    [PedObjects removeObjectForKey:[[theTimer userInfo]objectForKey:@"ObjectID"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",PedObjects);

    [theTimer invalidate];
    theTimer = nil;
}
```

A problem is that i cant copy the Timer Object to the dictionary...

How can i delete the right one after 2 sec in the fireTimer method?

with this i get the same result , if i have 2 selectors it will not remove 2 entries in my dictionary...

```
[PedObjects setObject:[PedMessage copy] forKey:[PedMessage objectForKey:@"ObjectID"]];
[self performSelector:@selector(delete:) withObject:[PedObjects objectForKey:[PedMessage objectForKey:@"ObjectID"]] afterDelay:2.0];


-(void)delete:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[PedMessage objectForKey:@"ObjectID"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",PedObjects);
    [PedObjects removeObjectForKey:[dict objectForKey:@"ObjectID"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",PedObjects);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this:

Instead of a timer, you call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delete:) withObject:yourDictionary afterDelay:2.0];

//delete implementation

-(void)delete:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict {
    [dict removeObjectForKey:@"yourKey"];
}
```

Comment: now i have the same problem, if i have 2 selectors it will not remove 2 entries in my dictionary...

Comment: @Phil: what do u mean by 2 selectors?

Comment: Similar but even easier might be: [dict performSelector:@selector(removeObjectForKey:) withObject:@"yourKey" afterDelay:2.0];